# conversion from float to Decimal in python-2.6: how to do it and why they didn't do it

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

Direct conversion from float to Decimal was implemented in python-2.7, both in Decimal's constructor and with the Decimal.from_float() classmethod.

Python-2.6 instead throws a TypeError suggesting to convert to string first:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string
```

so my usual workaround is this:

```
if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    Decimal.from_float = classmethod(lambda cls, x: cls(str(x)))
```

That's just a literary translation from the error message - and I just don't bother implementing it in the constructor too.

If it's that simple, why didn't they implement it in the first place instead of telling the user to do it in a TypeError? Is that the best method available (and by extension is that the one used in python-2.7 and newer?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your workaround is not the RightWayToDoIt(tm) because it loses information.  The lossless way to convert is shown in the recipe for `float_to_decimal()` shown in the [Decimal FAQ](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq).

The reason we didn't include Decimal.from_float in Python 2.6 is because we were being conservative about introducing unintentional interactions between binary floats and decimal floats.  By Python 2.7, this was all worked out and you can just write `Decimal(f)` where f is a binary float.

Other than the small nuisance in 2.6, I hope you're enjoying the Decimal module

Comment: I am *really* enjoying Decimal, it is one of those "simple things" upon which you can construct your application. In my case, Decimal is what manages *all* the money that's passing through our business, since we use a python app to manage orders and eventually generate invoices. Doing that with floats would have been a nightmare of roundings.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because the behavior of a direct conversion can be counterintuitive if you don't know [a few implementation details about floats](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). As stated in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.from_float):

> Note `Decimal.from_float(0.1)` is not the same as `Decimal('0.1')`.
>   Since `0.1` is not exactly representable in binary floating point, the
>   value is stored as the nearest representable value which is
>   `0x1.999999999999ap-4`. That equivalent value in decimal is
>   `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

If you convert to a string, you can control the precision you want to use, so you can get an accurate conversion to `Decimal`.

The new method was introduced in Python 2.7 - that's why it isn't in 2.6. New features are not backported to older versions.

Answer (score 0):

According to 2.7's [What's New](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html) documentation (emphasis added)

> Conversions between floating-point numbers and strings **are now
>   correctly rounded** on most platforms. These conversions occur in many
>   different places: str() on floats and complex numbers; the float and
>   complex constructors; numeric formatting; serializing and
>   deserializing floats and complex numbers using the marshal, pickle and
>   json modules; parsing of float and imaginary literals in Python code;
>   and **Decimal-to-float conversion**.

So, although they could have done that prior to 2.7, they apparently didn't feel comfortable doing that with the rounding problems that existed.

Comment: But `decimal.Decimal.from_float(0.1)` still gives you `Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')` in Python 2.7 (or 3.2, for that matter).

Comment: The rounding they are talking about is a bias towards zero in the least significant bit of the binary fraction.  Which apparently was not the previous behavior.  See http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.DefaultContext

Comment: @TimPietzcker, that's correct. When you write '0.1' you're actually writing a float that means 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 - then when you convert that to Decimal you're getting it right. There's no such thing as a IEEE754 float that actually means *exactly* 0.1 [you get the point]