# using zip function and getting errors using getcontext().prec =2

Tags: python

I am experiencing a problem when trying to use the getcontext().prec = 2 function, trying to get decimal results with only 2 decimals. I have experimented with several variations, but don't know why I can't transform float to string inside one of my lists. I am new using Python (2.6), and have not been able to find a solution for this. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
from __future__ import division
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 2

list_a = ['abc','def','ghi']
list_b = [123, 534, 345]
list_c = [Decimal(str(1/6)), Decimal(str(1/1234)), Decimal(str(2/9))]

for r,c,p in zip(list_a, list_b, list_c):
  print '{0} goes with {1} and with {2}%.'.format(r,c,p)
```

Returns

```
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

If  I eliminate the str() from the print line, the results are printed, but w/o constraints in the number of decimals. If I use Decimal() - w/o using str first, I get

```
'first convert the float to a string'.
```

Any insights? 
Cheers

Comment: I see no `str()` in the `print` line. Is your code up-to-date with the surrounding text? can you instead paste the different versions of code and the results?

Comment: Thank you. The 3 versions have been limited to altering list_c: one like it is now, one without the str, and the other one w/o Decimal(str, which prints the right thing with all the decimals (I only want 2).

Comment: The reason why it is not calculating to two decimal places is because it does an exact conversion from the result of the string
eg. str(1/7) = '0.142857142857' so Decimal(str(1/7))
Decimal('0.142857142857'). If you want it to use the prevision you set you must divide a decimal by another decimal as in Decimal(1)/Decimal(7). Printing is different from calculating to a decimal place as you can specify the number of decimal places but what you are doing is trying to calculate to two decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Decimal(str((2/9))
```

should be

```
Decimal(str(2/9))
```

You have an unclosed `)` in the code shown in the example.

**To display only two decimal places:**

```
from __future__ import division
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 2

list_a = ['abc','def','ghi']
list_b = [123, 534, 345]
list_c = [Decimal(str(1/6)), Decimal(str(1/1234)), Decimal(str(2/9))]
for r,c,p in zip(list_a, list_b, list_c):
  print '{0} goes with {1} and with {2:.2f}%.'.format(r,c,p)
```

Comment: Thank you, I did notice the parenthesis. However, after fixing that, the display is not constrained to two decimals. Any idea about what tio do to display only 2 decimals in the results?

Comment: Use {2:.2f} instead of {2}.
The . means precision and 2 is the number of decimal places, f means floating point

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the code you've posted represents what you're really working with, the following line:

```
list_c = [Decimal(str(1/6)), Decimal(str(1/1234)), Decimal(str((2/9))]
```

has a syntax error.  Count your parentheses (or use an editor that does matching for you).  I've changed the formatting to highlight the error:

```
list_c = [
    Decimal(str (   1 /6   )),
    Decimal(str (   1 /1234)),
    Decimal(str ( ( 2 /9   )),
    ]           # ^
                # here
```

If you remove the extraneous parentheses, the code runs without
errors.

Comment: This doesn't fix his real problem, getting the decimals to have two digits of precision.

Comment: I don't know.  I think his real problem was a syntax error.  Possibly our perspectives differ.

Comment: Thank you, I did notice the parenthesis. However, after fixing that, the display is not constrained to two decimals. Any idea about what tio do to display only 2 decimals in the results?

Answer (score 2):

The `SyntaxError` is trivially fixed but doesn't affect your problem of number of digits to display.

On Python 2.6 and older, you need to convert `float`s to `str`ings before converting them to `decimal`s. See [conversion from float to Decimal in python-2.6: how to do it and why they didn't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000318/conversion-from-float-to-decimal-in-python-2-6-how-to-do-it-and-why-they-didnt) for more information. On newer versions of Python, you can convert directly from a `float` to a `decimal`.

To quote from the [`decimal` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial):

> The significance of a new `Decimal` is determined solely by the number of digits input. Context precision and rounding only come into play during arithmetic operations.

To **round** a `Decimal` to a certain number of digits, use the normal Python [`round`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) function:

```
getcontext().prec = 2

                   # don't need str on Python 2.7+
list_c = [round(Decimal(str(x)), getcontext().prec) for x in (1/6, 1/1234, 2/9)]
```

or [`Decimal.quantize`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize):

```
getcontext().prec = 2
precision = Decimal(10) ** -getcontext().prec
list_c = [Decimal(x).quantize(precision) for x in (1/6, 1/1234, 2/9)]
```

If you only want to **display** two digits, but want to store full precision, use the [precision format specifier](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) in the `str.format`:

```
                # don't need str on Python 2.7+
list_c = [Decimal(str(x)) for x in (1/6, 1/1234, 2/9)] 

for r,c,p in zip(list_a, list_b, list_c):
  print '{0} goes with {1} and with {2:.2}%.'.format(r,c,p)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, the problem is the decimal part..can't get it to display only 2 digits.

Comment: @sgjc65 I edited my answer to add an option to only display two digits, along with the option to only store two digits.

Comment: Arf, thanks for your feedback. I tried the 2 versions and I get the same error I was getting before "Cannot convert float to Decimal". I dont know what's happening here. Did it work for you? Could it be Python 2.6?

Comment: @sgjc65 See the note in my code. In Python < 2.7, they do need to be strings. I'll update to show that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an extra ( in the t_c = line. Decimal(str((2/9))

Comment: Thanks. I did notice that and fixed it, but that's not the problem. After fixing it, the things still does not display 2 digits.